# How to add buttons created with for loop to layout from a java file?

Tags: java, android

```
Button button1 = new Button(this);
LinearLayout lay1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonLay)

for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {

        Button button1 = new Button(this);
}
```

It is my code.
How to add button1 to lay1?

Comment: Please add more information on what you want to achieve, what is the expected output?

Comment: I want to add different number of buttons to layout depending on some condition.

Comment: Your question title and post description are bit vague, can you precisely tell what you want to do?

Comment: What happened, when you added them to the layout view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the parent layout that will contain the buttons, like:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.yourlayout);
```

You will need something like a list to store the buttons:

```
List<Button> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then your loop:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
    Button button = new Button(this);  

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // code    
        }
    });

    list.add(button);
    layout.addView(button);
}
```

after you instantiate each button, 
add it to the list for later use and
add it to the parent Layout.